# How to use Windows SHBrowseforFolder function on 32 bit or 64 bit Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a module ("Module1.bas") in which conditional compilation constants are used as a programmatic test to determine the VBA version number (e.g. VBA7) and whether or not it's operating on a 64 bit platform.  Based on the result of that test, a Private type "BROWSEINFO" is declared as is the Windows API function SHBrowseforFolder which varies between the 32 and 64 bit types.  In the 32 bit version it returns a Long, whereas in the 64 bit version it returns a LongPtr.

That's working just fine.

However, in the same module, there is a function, "GetDirectory" which uses the datatype and SHBrowseforFolder function from the declaration mentioned above....except in this function, the return types are declared at the start of the GetDirectory function as Long and are thus "hard coded".  There doesn't seem to be any way of making the data type of these conditional on the VBA version and OS type.

Have I missed something here?

I'd REALLY like to be able to get the VBA to run depending on which Excel version it runs on instead of having 2 different versions.

Comment: Could you duplicate your function, one for 32bit and one for 64bit and use an `If...Then` statement to establsh `If 32bit Excel Then Do the 32bit function`... etc.?

Comment: Please show us the code to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, however, I was able to solve the problem.  Since a variable of type LongPtr resolves to Long in 32-bit versions of Office, and to LongLong in 64-bit versions of Office, I simply declared the two variables in the GetDirectory function as type LongPtr.  The errors just go away (assuming that the Windows API declarations are 32/64 bit specific using conditional compilation constants).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one code :) just put declare statements where you need.

```
Dim bits64 As Boolean
    #If VBA7 Then
         #If Win64 Then
            bits64 = True 'excel 64 bits
         #Else
            bits64 = False
         #End If
    #Else
        bits64 = False
    #End If
```

Second example:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function WritePrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias "WritePrivateProfileStringA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As Any, ByVal lpString As Any, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long
#Else
    Public Declare Function WritePrivateProfileString Lib "kernel32" Alias "WritePrivateProfileStringA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpKeyName As Any, ByVal lpString As Any, ByVal lpFileName As String) As Long
#End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies, however, I was able to solve the problem. Since a variable of type LongPtr resolves to Long in 32-bit versions of Office, and to LongLong in 64-bit versions of Office, I simply declared the two variables in the GetDirectory function as type LongPtr. The errors just go away (assuming that the Windows API declarations are 32/64 bit specific using conditional compilation constants).

Comment: @RobBarrow With Office 2010, Microsoft introduced VBA7, which contains a true pointer data type: LongPtr. This allows referencing 64-bit address space. So if you launch your VBA code on Excel 2007 or lower it will throw error. That's why you should use "#If VBA7 Then .. #Else .. #End If" and have 2 variants.